# iOS how to sign a request with Twitter consumer key and authentication tokens

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth

I am using Twitter digits with an iOS app, and when the users signs in with digits, the callback passes back a DGTSession object, with authenticationToken and authenticationTokenSecret NSString properties. After reading the documentation, I know that I can use the endpoint `account/verify_credential` to verify these tokens. This endpoint requires authentication, and I read from a post twittercommunity.com that I need to "Use the consumer key provided by TwitterKit, and the Digits tokens to sign the request". I know that the consumer is for the application, and I can get it with `[Twitter sharedInstance].authConfig.consumerKey` What I am confused about is "signing" the request. Does signing a request mean setting HTTP Header values? All I want to do is verify the authentication token and secret that is saved in the iOS Keychain.